# SQL query involving MAX

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

I have the following table I'd like to write a query for:

Table name: Stats_State_County

```
Column name    Type     Constraint 
-----------------------------------
Population     number 
CountyName     string
State          number   Primary key
```

I'd like to find the county with the maximum Population for each state. I'd like to only print out the name of the county and the max population for that county. Currently, I have something that returns the state and their max populations, but I need to return the county names instead of states.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can use this:

```
SELECT CountyName,
       MAX(Population)
FROM Stats_State_County
GROUP BY State
```

On earlier SQLite versions, a non-aggregated field like `CountName` is not guaranteed to come from the same record that matched the `MAX`, so you have to look up the name from the population in a separate step:

```
SELECT (SELECT CountyName
        FROM Stats_State_County
        WHERE State = T1.State
          AND Population = T1.MaxPop),
       MaxPop
FROM (SELECT State,
             MAX(Population) AS MaxPop
      FROM Stats_State_County
      GROUP BY State
     ) AS T1
```

Answer (score -1):

using a coorleated subquery to identify the max population for a county within the same state.

```
With CTE as
(Select 'A' as state,1000 as population, 'A1' as county FROM DUAL UNION ALL
Select 'A',1000, 'A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
Select 'A',1001, 'A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
Select 'A',1001, 'A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
Select 'A',1001, 'A4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
Select 'B',2000, 'B1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
Select 'B',2000, 'B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
Select 'B',2001, 'B2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
Select 'B',2002, 'B4' FROM DUAL) 
Select population, county from CTE A1 
  where a1.population >= (Select max(A2.population) from CTE A2 Where A2.State = A1.State) Group by population, county
```

Returns:

```
Population County
1001       A3
1001       A4
2002       B4
```

Replace CTE with your table name in both cases in this select and you should be ok.

Select population, county from CTE A1 
  where a1.population >= (Select max(A2.population) from CTE A2 Where A2.State = A1.State) Group by population, county

Note: if two counties have same population, then both counties are returned. if a county is for some reason listed twice, they are removed though the group by.  If the same county exists in two states with the same population, you probably aren't going to get the results you want unless you add state to the select and group by...

Comment: SQLite does not have CTEs.

Comment: @CL. Well the answer provided doesn't have a CTE either.  The with statement was just to get sample data.  You'll note after the returns, it states: Replace CTE with your table name in both cases in the select and you should be ok.